# In R: Indexing vectors by boolean comparison of a value in range: index==c(min : max)

Tags: r

In R, let's say we have a vector
`area = c(rep(c(26:30), 5), rep(c(500:504), 5), rep(c(550:554), 5), rep(c(76:80), 5))` and another vector `yield = c(1:100)`.
Now, say I want to index like so:

```
> yield[area==27]
[1]  2  7 12 17 22
> yield[area==501]
[1] 27 32 37 42 47
```

No problem, right? But weird things start happening when I try to index it by using `c(A, B)`. (and even weirder when I try `c(min:max)` ...)

```
> yield[area==c(27,501)]
[1]  7 17 32 42
```

What I'm expecting is of course the instances that are present in both of the other examples, not just some weird combination of them. This works when I can use the pipe OR operator:

```
> yield[area==27 | area==501]
 [1]  2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47
```

But what if I'm working with a range? Say I want index it by the range `c(27:503)`? In my real example there are a lot more data points and ranges, so it makes more sense, please don't suggest I do it by hand, which would essentially mean:

```
yield[area==27 | area==28 | area==29 | ... | area==303 | ... | area==500 | area==501]
```

There must be a better way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `%in%`.  Also notice that `c(27:503)` and `27:503` yield the same object.

```
> yield[area %in% 27:503]
 [1]   2   3   4   5   7   8   9  10  12  13  14  15  17
[14]  18  19  20  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  31  32
[27]  33  34  36  37  38  39  41  42  43  44  46  47  48
[40]  49  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87
[53]  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) Also, where on earth is this documented? How am I supposed to find it without asking? What do I ask the help about? The unhelpful help I call it :P

Comment: @gakera: it's in `?match`.  You're supposed to find it by guessing better keywords or reading the full reference manual. :-P  I think I first came across `match` via the "See Also" section of `?grep`.

Comment: Haha, guessing better keywords or reading the full manual, I love it! R is so user friendly :D Thank you again.

Comment: @gakera: out of curiosity, where would you expect something like that to be documented?  I.e. where did you look?  Maybe a link to `?match` should be added somewhere...

Comment: One of the tricks to learn (or gotcha's to avoid) is the need to quote some arguments to the "?" operator when seeking "help". Had you typed ?"%in%" , you would have been offered the help page for match(). There is also a link to "%in%" on the set function page which describes union(x, y), intersect(x, y), setdiff(x, y), and setequal(x, y) .... all useful in the right circumstance since they return the original elements rather than a logical vector.  [I checked "An introduction to R" .. nothing about %in% or match().]

Comment: @DWin : "An introduction to R" is very much outdated by now. If you write a new one, you have an immediate bestseller. But it'll take you time to do it good and thoroughly. I'm busy on one for a year, but R changes faster than I can finish that thing. It is "not part of the job description" after all...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use subset?

```
subset(yield, area > 26 & area < 504) ## for indexes
subset(area, area > 26 & area < 504) ## for values
```

Comment: Why not use it?  One reason: to heed the Warning section in `?subset`, since `yield[area > 26 & area < 504]` is equivalent.

Comment: Warning: This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like ‘[’, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.

Comment: @Brandon: please don't take me too seriously here.  I started hunting for reasons "why not" since that was in the prelude to your answer. ;-)

Comment: No worries. Interestingly, in my ?subset I don't have a section that says that. What version are you using?